# How can I copy an asset folder programatically depending upon a constant?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a Unity project in which I have 200 games and some 350 scenes. Now I want to make separate builds for each game. All my assets are present in `Assets/IgnoredAssets/ABC` folder. To include these assets in my current build the assets of the current game (say ABC) needs to be in `Assets/Resources/ABC`.

I want Unity to take these `Assets/IgnoredAssets/ABC` files and copy them to `Assets/Resources` before making build depending upon a constant defined in some file.

I want a kind of automation so that when I mention in my constant file `string gameName="ABC";` it automatically picks its assets, paste them in `Resources` and builds for me.

How can I do this?

Comment: Go through [AssetDatabase](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html) and [BuildPipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.html) documentation. They have all the functions that you require to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

First of, you should have separate projects for individual games and not all games in one project.

You can just move the assets around if you know what the current select game is. First, move the current game back.

```
AssetDatabase.MoveAsset("Assets/Resources/<filenanme>", "Assets/Resources/<currentgame>/<filename>");
```

Now, move the next game into the  asset folder.

```
AssetDatabase.MoveAsset("Assets/IgnoredAssest/<newgame>/<filenanme>", "Assets/Resources/<filename>");
```